# FCM receive data in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

There are two types of `FCM` Messages:

- **Display Messages** - The notifications received in background and the data payload goes to System Tray for which apparently I have no way of receiving data unless User interacts with the notification itself.
- **Data Messages** - The data received when app is in foreground and `onMessageRecieved` service event is called. I save that in a database on my android device and is available from there at anytime.

Does this mean that if user dismisses the notification, when app is in background, I have no way of receiving the sent data? Can I still save it in a local android phone database from there or do I have to make an explicit (some other method) server call to my app server for the remaining data?

If not, does `FCM` extend to this extent? Overriding `handleIntent` is a method but not recommended and it is `final` now so no chance there, I guess.

Also, is there a better solution other than `FCM` if none of the above is applicable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876257/push-notification-works-incorrectly-when-app-is-on-background-or-not-running

Comment: This isn't mentioned in FCM documentation. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193700/retrieve-notification-values-from-a-notification-in-system-tray-android-firebase

Comment: @TimCastelijns is there a way to know if app is in foreground or background based at data/notification received?

Comment: @MashalRashid no