# Intent cant receive data in android

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, android-activity

I want to send data from intent if my intent is null then simple open my main activity. This is my tryout but its not work for me.

From one activity to send

```
intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("androidkey",body);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

and receive time

```
 String uid;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
 uid = intent.getStringExtra("androidkey");
```

Oncreate method of main activity

```
 if (uid.equals("hello")){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class));

        }else if (uid.equals("")||uid.equals(null)){

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
```

Please tell me the solution for this 
because its crash my application.

what actually i want to do in my code is

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));


        }

        //Check if the message contains notification

        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Mesage body:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String body) {
 if (body.equals("Image Upload Successfully")){
            intent= new Intent(this, Image_Gallery.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        }else if (body.equals("Video Upload Successfully")){

            intent = new Intent(this, Video_Gallary.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        }else if (body.equals("Home Work Are Uploaded")){

            intent = new Intent(this, HomeWork.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        }
```

when my app is in foreground and notification arrived its open perfect page but when application is not in foreground it's open Mainactivity

so please tell me what should i can do for that..?

Comment: Please post logcat error. It help everyone to found the issue.

Comment: Do not decide which activity to load in MainActivity, when it is already started, but before creating the intent. If you have any android key, start the About_School activity and if not..start the main. So...decide which activity to load at the place where you create the Intent, not in the resulting activity.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793746/notification-to-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Sending activity,

```
    Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
newActivity1.putExtra("androidkey", body);
startActivity(newActivity1);
```

Receiving Activity,

```
 String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("androidkey");
```

Or,

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String uid;

if (extras != null) {
    uid= extras.getString("androidkey");

}
```

For firebase try something like this,

```
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        Bundle bundle = data.getBundle("notification");

                if (bundle != null) {
                   String text = bundle.getString("text");
                    String body = bundle.getString("body");
    }
}
```

or,

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
        Log.e("dataMessage",remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        try
        {
            Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);
            Log.e("JSON_OBJECT", object.toString());
      }
   }
```

Comment: actually i want to implement in MyFirebaseMessagingService

Comment: so when some message receive then open particular activity but its not works for me.

Comment: Oh okay you didn't mention that in your question

Comment: try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181654/firebase-fcm-open-activity-and-pass-data-on-notification-click-android

Comment: please check this URL and its my question but its not works then i will try for this

Comment: i have edited my answer,please check what that text and body comes,please log it and let me know

Comment: check my answer,also log this one also, Log.d("Bundle123::", bundle + "");

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference @sunisha sindhu

Comment: i have edited my answer check with it,and tell me what that dataMessage value getting

Answer (score 0):

Okay, because a comment only may be to meaningless.

Do not decide where to go, in one of your activities, but at the 
place where you create the intent.

Like this:

```
Intent startIntent;
if(body == null || body.isEmpty()){
    startIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
}else{
    startIntent = new Intent(context, About.class);
    startIntent.putExtra("androidkey",body);
}

startIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(startIntent);
```

Comment: Please tell me why or I can't help you.

Comment: actually i want to implement in MyFirebaseMessagingService

Comment: so when some message receive then open particular activity but its not works for me.

Comment: So..you have a service where you receive the firebase cloud messages correct? Therefor in this service, start the correct activity, with the given key as bove.

Comment: please check this what actually i want to implement but its not work for me then i will try this

Comment: Ok, instead of creating a new question, you should consider improving the old one and get answers there.