# Messages not loading on clicking Firebase notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I have a created a Firebase application using the tutorial given [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/). As I am a beginner to Android, please help me solving this. My app has a only one activity.

When I send a message from my Firebase console, I am able to see the message and the toast on screen when the app is open. **However, if the app is not running, I am able to see the notification from Firebase in Notifications Bar but on clicking it neither the toast comes or the message gets shown on the screen.**
Everything works well only for the very first time the app is installed. 
How can I solve this problem? Kindly help. Below are my codes:

Activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.unss.pramod.firebasetest.activity.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_push_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="26dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_reg_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
    private TextView txtRegId, txtMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtRegId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_reg_id);
        txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_push_message);

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                // checking for type intent filter
                if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                    // gcm successfully registered
                    // now subscribe to `global` topic to receive app wide notifications
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

                    displayFirebaseRegId();

                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                    // new push notification is received

                    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    txtMessage.setText(message);
                }
            }
        };

        displayFirebaseRegId();
    }

    // Fetches reg id from shared preferences
    // and displays on the screen
    private void displayFirebaseRegId() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
        String regId = pref.getString("regId", null);

        Log.e(TAG, "Firebase reg id: " + regId);

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regId))
            txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id: " + regId);
        else
            txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id is not received yet!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // register GCM registration complete receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));

        // register new push message receiver
        // by doing this, the activity will be notified each time a new message arrives
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));

        // clear the notification area when the app is opened
        NotificationUtils.clearNotifications(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Firebase Instance ID service.java

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        // Saving reg id to shared preferences
        storeRegIdInPref(refreshedToken);

        // sending reg id to your server
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        registrationComplete.putExtra("token", refreshedToken);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {
        // sending gcm token to server
        Log.e(TAG, "sendRegistrationToServer: " + token);
    }

    private void storeRegIdInPref(String token) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("regId", token);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Firebase messaging service.java

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        }else{
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }

    private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
        Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

        try {
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
            String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
            String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
            JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

            Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
            Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
            Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
            Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
            Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


            if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                // play notification sound
                NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
                notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
            } else {
                // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

                // check for image attachment
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
                } else {
                    // image is present, show notification with image
                    showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text only
     */
    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text and image
     */
    private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
    }
}
```

Config.java

```
public class Config {

    // global topic to receive app wide push notifications
    public static final String TOPIC_GLOBAL = "global";

    // broadcast receiver intent filters
    public static final String REGISTRATION_COMPLETE = "registrationComplete";
    public static final String PUSH_NOTIFICATION = "pushNotification";

    // id to handle the notification in the notification tray
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE = 101;

    public static final String SHARED_PREF = "ah_firebase";
}
```

Kindly help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onMessageReceived` method will be called only when your application is opened/foreground when you send "Notification type message". If want to run `onMessageReceived` either your application in close then send "Data message". Click [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messages-with-both-notification-and-data-payloads) to learn more about data message. Send data notification from server. 
JSON sample for data message taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38795553/3529309

```
{
  "to": "/topics/dev_journal",
   "data": {
       "text":"text",
       "title":"",
       "line1":"Journal",
       "line2":"test"
   }
}
```

Use `push.php` class from tutorial [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) you mentioned to send data message.

Answer (score 1):

For notifications to be clickable when your app is in the background, you need the `click_action` attribute in your notification payload.

Please check this [section](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjP-vesl-rUAhXMP48KHQ-nD9sQygQIKDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fhttp-server-ref%23notification-payload-support&usg=AFQjCNEQeBMYQX-1IYsUDKnjj7OtYhlFIA) of the Firebase docs.

Also, when you define the `click_action` attribute, you will also need a corresponding `<action>` attribute in the `<intent-filter>` of the activity that you wish to launch.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hi8IPLNq59o) explains it in quite a detailed manner.

Though, please note that you can not set the `click__action` attribute if you're sending notifications from the Firebase Console. You can only do so if you send a notification from your own Admin server or using Firebase Cloud Functions.

Lastly, in the activity that is launched, you can set additional `Data` using the data attribute ( also shown in the same doc that I linked above ). And when you launch your app by clicking on a notification, you can  obtain the notification data using `getIntent()`. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40185654/7626492) for more details on how to do that.