# How to open a specific activity when the app is running in background?

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I need to open a specific activity when the app is running in background (not killed) using `Firebase` notification system. As per the doc, Notification tray will open the default activity and send the intent to it.

To open a specific activity, I added an  `<Intent>` to `Manifest` file:

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Sending data through `Postman` as a `Post` request:

```
{ 
  "notification" : {
      "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1":".activity.TemActivity_",
      "body" : "update !"
   }, 
  "data": {
      "type":0,
      "question":"open the activity"
 },
 "to": "dDmXZa9k6-o:APA91bEx91oyYnOyzK3kX839EqbvA2CgY74s-
fLUs8MCYZzVmnp-RpgyI3zicEFVS37K7A4kPpbbqYU9hMBEbs-
PrBXlSTYTOBVd7O3CNvl1vaTEbGIHjLLRTWvEK2VRCvJkhQTXWtr3"
}
```

However, I am getting the notificaiton and when I am clicking the `notificaiton` tray. It's always opening the default intent activity. What Am I doing wrong here to open the `TeamActivity_` (Using android annotation)

## Edit-1

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public String TAG = "Data";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    System.out.println("data");
  }
}
```

My `token` is valid because I can see the notification tray.

Comment: will you please share your java code of firebase messaging

Comment: @AshishPandey Firebase messaging code for what? Are you asking about `onMessageReceived`?

Comment: yes just post the whole code you have written in that class

Comment: Let me post it but it has nothing to do with "Getting notification when the app is getting killed". Debug will get there only when the app is open

Comment: Possibly helpful (if not a duplicate) post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40181654/4625829)

Comment: @AL.Thanks for the reference but the answer there is just telling the way to accept the data from intent (Which is working for me). I am not able to open a specific activity when the notification tray is getting tapped

Comment: @komalsharma see my answer hope this will give you some idea how to achieve it.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Your code will only work when the app is in foreground. I am looking for a way when the app is in background.

Comment: I am using this code even if the app is in background or foreground this will generate the notification in tray for me.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper It will generate the notification tray but what next. I am asking that I have to open a specific activity intent not the default intent when app is in background. What you are saying is correct but not the complete answer

Comment: @komalsharma whenever the notification come from Firebase it always call the onMessageReceived() method inside this method you just need to check the if(condition) { Intent notificationIntent1 = new Intent(this, TempActivity.class); notificationIntent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); this.startActivity(notificationIntent1); }.
I don't know where you are facing the problem but this works for me everytime since I was used the GCM and still in FCM it works like a charm.

Comment: @Andy Checkout my answer.

Comment: @AmitPal Cool it works!

Comment: @AmitPal I didn't see anything new. This is the same post which is the question. She already said that she added intent-filter so what's new in this post. Anyways :)

Comment: @AndyDeveloper I think you missed a bug in it. Have a look at the code and you will that she is not using "Click_action" in `post` request. Be precisely ` "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1":".activity.TemActivity_",` should be ` "click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1",`. Got it?

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Your answer will be perfect for "Foreground" not the "Background".

Comment: I was thought it is a payload. If you parse that payload without using intent filter in that case my answer is perfectly working.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper It will not even work in that case dude!. Let me tell you what will happen in your scenario. Your application is running in the background. A new notification will come and when you click on that notification tray `Nothing will change`. The reason: Because `FirebaseMessagingService ` is only capable of accepting notification when the app is in the foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you a simple example.

In `AndroidManifest` (Let's say you want to open SampleActivity_)

```
    <activity android:name=".activity.SampleActivity_"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Now make a `Post` request

```
{ 
 "notification" : {
       "click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1",
       "body" : "new Symulti update !"
 }, 
  "data": {
      "type":0,
      "question":"what are you doing?"
},
   "to": "cfXBKN_vhFw:APA91bH268KeCeFLlp0OHH-
          UNPgR_njeNmJET0PvrcrHe6VLN-
          w6UQCCO_LbN0TeNhpjqDDStNnt4t0FGQ6S5puz49QSdsK1BKb8R7Q1uYNpP_
          UqsRIETuOh1TRst
          JAsfJS7VI7Atpfx"
}
```

I have tested it and working perfectly!

**Only when app is running in background**