# When app in background firebase notification have notification with payload then remote message method call or not

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I will try to getting data when app in background like this format

```
{
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    },
    "data" : {
     "Nick" : "Mario",
     "body" : "great match!",
     "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
   }
}
```

so data is delivered on onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) method or not i don't know can any one help me for this issue.

Comment: if you are using FCM then it will be delivered in `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For notifications to be clickable when your app is in the background, you need the `click_action` attribute in your notification payload.

Please check this [section](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjP-vesl-rUAhXMP48KHQ-nD9sQygQIKDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fhttp-server-ref%23notification-payload-support&usg=AFQjCNEQeBMYQX-1IYsUDKnjj7OtYhlFIA) of the Firebase docs.

Also, when you define the `click_action` attribute, you will also need a corresponding `<action>` attribute in the `<intent-filter>` of the activity that you wish to launch.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hi8IPLNq59o) explains it in quite a detailed manner.

Though, please note that you can not set the `click__action` attribute if you're sending notifications from the Firebase Console. You can only do so if you send a notification from your own Admin server or using Firebase Cloud Functions.

Lastly, in the activity that is launched, you can set additional `Data` using the data attribute ( also shown in the same doc that I linked above ). And when you launch your app by clicking on a notification, you can  obtain the notification data using `getIntent()`. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40185654/7626492) for more details on how to do that.

For example, if your notification payload has the following structure,

```
payload = {
  notification: {
    title: `You ordered a new product`,
    click_action : 'HANDLE_NOTIFICATION',

  },
  data : {
        product_id : 'ABC98292',
        type : `Clothes`,
        product_name : 'Cotton spring shirt'
    }
};
```

then, put the filter in the  tag of the activity that you want to open when the notification is clicked. An example is the following :-

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="HANDLE_NOTIFICATION" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then you can get the product_id from the notification using `getIntent().getStringsExtra("product_id")` and so on.

This way, you'll be opening the required activity, and can populate it with the relevant details obtained from your notification.