# How to do some logic when clicking push notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app receives FCM notification when the admin activate the user account from control panel, I want to to do some action from a method like a toast or deleting some data from my db when the user clicks the push notification.!

Is this possible?

here's the code inside `FirebaseMessagingService` class

```
public class CustomFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

  public static String INTENT_FILTER = "INTENT_FILTER";

  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    try {

      if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_FILTER);
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), intent);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    }


    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Intent intent) {

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
        .setContentTitle("UPDATE")
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For notifications to be clickable when your app is in the background, you need the `click_action` attribute in your notification payload. This is completely separate from the `FirebaseMessagingService` and other such classes, because these work when the app is in the foreground.

Please check this [section](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjP-vesl-rUAhXMP48KHQ-nD9sQygQIKDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fhttp-server-ref%23notification-payload-support&usg=AFQjCNEQeBMYQX-1IYsUDKnjj7OtYhlFIA) of the Firebase docs.

Also, when you define the `click_action` attribute, you will also need a corresponding `<action>` attribute in the `<intent-filter>` of the activity that you wish to launch.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hi8IPLNq59o) explains it in quite a detailed manner.

Though, please note that you can not set the `click__action` attribute if you're sending notifications from the Firebase Console. You can only do so if you send a notification from your own Admin server or using Firebase Cloud Functions.

Lastly, in the activity that is launched, you can set additional `Data` using the data attribute ( also shown in the same doc that I linked above ). And when you launch your app by clicking on a notification, you can  obtain the notification data using `getIntent()`. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40185654/7626492) for more details on how to do that.

It really is quite simple and elegant.

**UPDATE**

For example, if your notification payload has the following structure,

```
payload = {
  notification: {
    title: `You ordered a new product`,
    click_action : 'HANDLE_NOTIFICATION',

  },
  data : {
        product_id : 'ABC98292',
        type : `Clothes`,
        product_name : 'Cotton spring shirt'
    }
};
```

then, put the filter in the  tag of the activity that you want to open when the notification is clicked. An example is the following :-

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="HANDLE_NOTIFICATION" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then you can get the product_id from the notification using `getIntent().getStringsExtra("product_id")` and so on.

This way, you'll be opening the required activity, and can populate it with the relevant details obtained from your notification.

Comment: I tried, but no luck with background, clicking only opens the activity but doesn't perform the condition of the passed data coming from the intent extra, it only apply when i click from foreground..!!? any help here..! I did what in the video exactly

Comment: @SamZar I don't know what exactly is not working in your code, so I made an edit to my answer  that is generic and should cover your problem. Please check the edit, and get back if it still doesn't work.

Comment: It worked now :D , I didn't work before because I put the `value` of the data inside the `getStringExtra` , but once I replace it with the `key` it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it just pass some integer value with intent using 
`putextra` for a reference in activity and in `onCreate` of activity 
class just check the if condition and make changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a `LocalBroadcastReceiver` to listener to incoming notification inside you activity :

```
boolean isReceiverRegistered = false ; // to not create receiver twice

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver();
    //code
 }

private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case YOUR_ACTION:
                    handleIncomingAction(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

private void registerReceiver() {
        if (!isReceiverRegistered) {
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(YOU_ACTION);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
            isReceiverRegistered = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this but nothing happend, what is `handleIncomingAction` really is in your code..!? are you sure this works for when clicking the notification when the app is background !?

Answer (score 1):

The logic is to add an extra parameter in the intent and check for that in the launching activities onCreate method

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Intent intent) {
// set extra param
intent.putExtra("is_from_notification", true);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
    .setContentTitle("UPDATE")
    .setContentText(messageBody)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

In your activity

```
 @override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstance);

     if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("is_from_notification", false)) {
        // TODO: do whatever you want in here
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add a "flag" when you start an intent for an activity, to see from which activity the user comes from like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NotificationActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("call_from", "NotificationActivity");
```

and to get back:

```
String fromActivity = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("call_from");
if(fromActivity.equals(NotificationActivity.class.getSimpleName())) {
    //call your method to delete what you want
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Try add use `this` in stead of the name of your activity.