# Android : unable to get data payload in firebase notification message

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Might be some small thing I am missing here.
I am unable to get the data payload for the notification message. What is wrong with this code? :

```
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   Intent intent  = getIntent();
Set<String> strings =  extras.keySet();

for(String each: strings){

    Log.d("notiffff", each);

}
```

This code executes after I click the notification message from the system tray (from a notification delivered in the background). The optional data payload I put in the console does not appear here. I want it, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase (FCM): open activity and pass data on notification click. android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181654/firebase-fcm-open-activity-and-pass-data-on-notification-click-android)

Comment: Try adding in the keys you included in your `data` payload.